# Rails 3.1 and Asset Pipeline: Trouble on deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I just switched from Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 to 3.1.0 and I would like to deploy my asset files by using the Capistrano gem (my local machine is a MacOs running Snow Leopard, my remote machine is running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid). So, as wrote in the [Official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), I uncomment the `load 'deploy/assets'` in my `Capfile` like this:

```
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Now, when I run the `cap deploy` command I get the following error (the error is explained at the bottom):

```
...

  * executing "cd /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925223032 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["<my_web_site_ip>"]
    [<my_web_site_ip>] executing command
 ** [out :: <my_web_site_ip>] (in /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925223032)
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] rake aborted!
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:4:in `require'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:2:in `require'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb:12:in `load'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb:12:in `block in <class:TestUnitRailtie>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `call'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `block in load_tasks'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `each'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:183:in `load_tasks'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:395:in `block in load_tasks'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:395:in `load_tasks'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:99:in `load_tasks'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925223032/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
*** [err :: ] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
    command finished in 4301ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925223032; true"
    servers: ["<my_web_site_ip>"]
    [<my_web_site_ip>] executing command
    command finished in 377ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925223032 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on <my_web_site_ip>
```

So, I tried to solve the problem following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku):

```
# Rakefile
require 'rake/dsl_definition'

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

<MyApplicationName>::Application.load_tasks
```

After I run again the `cap deploy` command I get the following error:

```
...

  * executing "cd /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925160036 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["<my_web_site_ip>"]
    [<my_web_site_ip>] executing command
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
 ** [out :: <my_web_site_ip>] (in /<application_absolute_path>/releases/20110925160036)
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'

...
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'
...
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] WARNING: DSL method Object#mkdir_p called at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `mkdir_p'
...

*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] rake aborted!
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] stack level too deep
*** [err :: <my_web_site_ip>] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/ostruct.rb:92
    command finished in 48421ms
```

**Where the code related to Capistrano is wrong? How to use correctly the `load 'deploy/assets'` statement in order to make the deployment process to work?**

Comment: Are you using the latest Capistrano and Rake gems?

Comment: @Richard Hulse - Yes, I think so: `$ rake -V # => rake, version 0.9.2`, `$ cap -V # => Capistrano v2.8.0`.

Comment: Try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku

Comment: @Richard Hulse - I already tried that solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: Rats! It might pay to ask on the Capistrano mailing list then. Sorry I could not help...

Comment: what happens when you run `rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets assets:precompile` on your dev machine?

Comment: Do you have installed the same gems on the production server as well?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried simply defining your own task? That's what I did [when I ran into this issue](http://www.tigraine.at/2011/09/25/securely-managing-database-yml-when-deploying-with-capistrano/):

```
task :precompile, :role => :app do  
  run "cd #{release_path}/ && rake assets:precompile"  
end  
after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:precompile"
```

You do need [RVM initialization](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/) for this if you use RVM